# What's the minimum energy (thresold) for a proton-electron collision and creation of a neutron?

Tags: particle-physics

And Is it the same than for a proton-proton collision and creation of an antiproton?

Comment: Have you tried line-reversing neutron decay?

Answer (score 2):

Particle interactions are studied within the [standard model of particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) physics and the Feynman diagrams are the tool to calculate how probable the outcome is.

In your question you are asking whether a proton can by interacting with an electron turn into a neutron.

[image: protneut]

This interaction is possible, and the probability can be calculated using the method of the diagram above, and energy and momentum conservation has to be applied.

The [mass of the neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron) is ~Mev/c 939.6, the [mass of the proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton) is ~938.3 Mev/c .

So there *is* a threshold  for the interaction to happen.

> same than for a proton-proton collision and creation of an antiproton?

The masses and energies entering in proton proton collisions and the complexity of the interaction to produce antiprotons , with their large mass, while also conserving charge and quantum numbers make the answer "definitely not even similar".

Answer (score 0):

There is no electron-proton energy threshold for this process.  You would also need an antineutrino absorption for this process to yield a neutron and the energy of the antineutrino would also enter into the threshold calculation.

Comment: You could emit (and then ignore) a neutrino instead of requiring a three-body collision.

Comment: @rob You are correct, and that is exactly what happens with electron capture where a bound s-state electron collides with a proton inside a nucleus to create a neutron and a neutrino,